# Punishment for zina

Tags: zina

Is spending time with our fiance  wherein we hug each other , holds hand and kiss each other  not on lips but on cheeks of face but our intention is not for zina,that is so because i love her so much.So,does this things should be consider as zina

Comment: see this http://islamqa.info/en/27259

Answer (score 5):

It may not be ZINA but it definitely leads to it.

@Hanif has already explained a beautiful hadeeth.

And let's look at another hadeeth:
The prophet (S) said, "It is better for you to be stabbed in the head with an iron needle than to touch the hand of a woman who is not permissible to you."

Source: At-Tabarani in Al-Kabir, #486. 
Sheikh Al-Albaani stated that this is authentic in Sahih al-Jaami' it is sahih #5045]

So leave a side kissing and hugging. You can't even touch her!

If you 'love her so much' you would do the honourable thing of marrying her.

This is madness where some youth, particularly in the west sleep together and sometimes even have kids before deciding to get married. Please don't fall into the trap of such miserable life-styles.

I don't think any sane, decent person will tolerate his daughter or sister being kissed and hugged by a guy who claims to love her?

Back on your subject, how do you draw the line that kissing on the cheek and elsewhere is ok but not the lips? Who made these laws?

Islam is revealed and not man-made. So we just take it and put it into action. We don't customise it like some product in a factory.

Comment: Here's another link warning against touching a woman who is not mahram to you (includes your to-be wife): http://islamnewsroom.com/answers/93-shaking-hands-with-women/

Comment: I disagree with "some youth, particularly in the west". I think you have to travel around to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

No. Zina is explicitly defined as *penetrative sex* between partners who are not married.

Comment: Because, as I stated in my answer, Zina has an explicit **definition** by scholars which this doesn't cover.

Comment: What do you have to say about committing zina with your eyes?

Comment: "zina with your eyes" is a euphemism. It isn't *actual* zina that is a punishable with a *hadd*. It is a sin, yes, but it is *not* zina.

Comment: Its not a complete answer. "No".. so they can do the above things mentioned in the ques.

Comment: http://islamqa.info/en/27259